# Trying to check if beforeinstallprompt is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm having a difficult time check for undefined pwa install prompt(). I've tried checking based on the following code but I can't get it working. First snippet is how I set up the listener:

```
`let deferredPrompt;
     window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', evt => {
     evt.preventDefault();`enter code here`
     deferredPrompt = evt;     
 });`
```

Then later in a separate function i tried to check in 2 different ways, but i cannot catch the case if the prompt is undefined

```
`if(deferredPrompt !== null && deferredPrompt !== 'undefined') { // chromium browser exists
     promptBanner.style.display = 'none';
        // Show Chrome a2hs modal
        deferredPrompt.prompt().then(() => {
            deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
                if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                    console.log('User accepted the install prompt');
                } else {
                    console.log('User dismissed the install prompt');
                    deferredPrompt = null;
                }
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Prompt is not available" + err);
        });`
```

Does anyone have any advice. Thanks and i hope you are all safe!
Perry

Answer (score -1):

First listen for the `beforeinstallprompt` event using this code.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (event) => {
   console.log("beforeinstallprompt fired -> ", event);
   window.deferredPrompt = event;
   document.getElementById("yourInstallButtonContainer").classList.toggle("hidden", false);
});
```

Now, you can handle the install button click using this code.

```
const promptEvent = window.deferredPrompt;
if (!promptEvent) return;
promptEvent.prompt();
promptEvent.userChoice.then((choice) => {
  console.log("User selected -> ", choice);
  window.deferredPrompt = null;
  document
    .getElementById("yourInstallButtonContainer")
    .classList.toggle("hidden", true);
});
```

You can log a statement if your `promptEvent` is undefined. The above code just return if `!promptEvent` is `true`